# Is there any possibility to auto login to sites via Facebook?

Tags: ios, applications, password, login

When browsing Facebook via the iOS app one often browses websites through the app. Some websites need login and since the FB app doesn't support password handlers it's a difficult login process.

So any suggestion about how to handle this the easiest way?

I'd wish one could automatically open all sites in Safari at least if FB doesn't want to support password handlers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a design decision by Facebook, and the best you can do is go into **Settings** → **Safari** → **Passwords**, where you can copy/paste your passwords into the Facebook browser to log into individual websites.

You can also specify a text replacement string for your email address under **Settings** → **General** → **Keyboard** → **Text Replacements**, so you can enter it more quickly into the Facebook app.

Comment: Thanks! You can imagine how much more work there is to go through iOS to find my passwords, instead of having them autofilled. It's a ridiculous UX from Facebook's side.

Comment: I do have text replacement for my email address, but many sites use a username instead and no matter what, I still have to look up my password. Thanks for the good advice though!

Comment: I agree that it’s incredibly tedious, especially since sites occasionally log you out. It doesn’t seem particularly difficult to integrate with the keychain, as I’ve seen some smaller apps implement that on their login screen, or in their Safari View Controller. Sadly I’ve never had any luck getting Facebook to implement any of my suggestions/requests.

Answer (score 0):

I've turn on Keychain in iCloud Settings. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085
Afterwards save the Facebook ID and Password. It will autofill for further app permission.

As I know it's happened only when you use iOS Safari in Private Mode with Do not Track and accept cookies from Current website.

Try to disable all those settings.

Comment: I can't follow what you meant to say.

Comment: I can read it autofill and how iCloud Keychain works https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085